# A question in paper " A note on Odd zeta values " by Tanguy Rivoal and Wadim Zudilin on page 6

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

I am studying research paper " A note on odd zeta values " by Tanguy Rivoal and Wadim Zudilin .

> Note-> This question has been closed 2 times on math.stackexchange . Earlier it was posted on MathOverflow but people here said it should be posted on math stackexchange. But  they have closed it 2 times consecutively.

> Please help I am badly struck on it.

Notations:
[image]

> I couldn't think about how authors write the equation - we obtain $\phi_{(n) }^{-1} ( F(t) (t+m)^5 )_{ t=-m} $ $ \in \mathbb{Z} $ for m= 0 ,1,...,n by defininig $\phi_{(n)} = \prod_{2√n<p\leq n } p^{\rho_0(n/p) } $ .

Kindly see last 2 lines of image posted below , I have underlined(in black) the part in which i have question .[image]

[image]

I have understood everything in research paper till this argument but  I don't have a clue on how authors derives the underlined part.

> I think  they are using [12, lemma1] (Paper-" One of odd zeta values from $\zeta(5)$ to $\zeta(25) $ is irrational by elementary means " By Wadim Zudilin )whose image I am posting below but unfortunately  I am not able to obtain this relation from the lemma.
> Image of lemma ->

[image]

> It would be really helpful for me if anyone can tell me  how to deduce this equation  $\phi_{(n) }^{-1} ( F(t) (t+m)^5 )_{ t=-m} $ $\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: first of all, did you try to ask the authors?

Comment: Authors are almost always happy to answer questions from people interested in their work – the whole idea that someone is actually reading their paper is immensely satisfying.

Comment: Simulposted to m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521840/an-argument-in-lemma-of-research-paper-irrationallity-of-values-of-riemann-zet without notice to either site. That's an abuse – please don't do that.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson questions are different, please don't downvote. This question is different and harder than question asked on stackexchange. I request you to take your downvote back

Comment: @Dxdxdade I downvoted because that's also a straightforward question -- just a matter of working out the notations. Please don't post on MO unless you have a *serious* doubt about an argument in a paper. Please consider using MSE instead. By the way, I don't like how you post the questions. It's better if you rewrite things in usual LaTeX without images. It will also benefit your understanding.

Comment: @Dxdxdade By "serious doubt" I mean that you suspect that there is something wrong/incomplete in the argument, and you can substantiate that. So simply "not having any clue" is not enough to ask here. My advice would be that you rewrite the arguments (maybe taking particular cases and introducing your own notation) until you recognise which basic properties or theory you can apply.

Comment: You have your answer now. Please don't use the bounty system to evade normal community moderation. As has been pointed out, the question probably won't be considered appropriate for this site, and so if the community wants to close it, they should be allowed to.

Comment: If a question is closed on MSE that is not in itself a justification for asking it on here, especially if the people on MSE have the view that the question is unclear or too basic

Comment: Not that I care (I use MO less and less), but the bounty for this question disappeared.  Funny.

Comment: @DamienC see comment of Todd Trimble

Comment: You had an answer in January, Arnold, which you accepted. What purpose does it serve to introduce edits to the question now?

Comment: The edits you have made to this and other old questions are mostly cosmetic and do not appreciably improve those posts. I don't see how that will get you out of a ban. It might be worth contacting the moderators for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very easy (and this is probably why people are telling you that the question is not appropriate for MO).

You have a certain integer $X$, and you'd like to prove that $X$ is divisible by $\Phi_n$.

You know that $v_p(X)\geq\rho_0(n/p)$ for every odd prime $2\sqrt n\leq p\leq n$ (from the "Notations" section), meaning that $X$ is divisible by the $\rho_0(n/p)$-th power of $p$.

Hence you're done.

Comment: here $\psi(t) $ = $\frac {\Gamma'(t) } { \Gamma(t) } $ and $\rho_0(t) $ is as defined in original question